# Favorite Answers and Questions from second quarter of 2015

Tags: discussion, blog

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from April 1st 2015 through June 30th 2015.

Personally, I think my favorite question to answer was:

[Could the Earth-2149 Squirrel Girl destroy Colonel America's shield?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89322/could-the-earth-2149-squirrel-girl-destroy-colonel-americas-shield)

Obviously it doesn't have to be something you asked or answered. If you found someone else's question or answer amazing. Let me know.

These will of course go into a blog post summary. http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/category/qotw/

*At this point, I am just trying to be able to submit the post without it saying this is a duplicate.*

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2015/04/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2015/04/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2015/04/01)

Comment: [All answers created in Q2 - 2015](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/292102/answers-created-in-q2-2015)

Comment: [All questions created in Q2 - 2015](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/292100/questions-created-in-q2-2015)

Comment: @Mooz They are all good? ALL of them?

Comment: Huzzah!  I'm at the top of two lists!

Comment: @JackBNimble Not necessarily, I was just pointing people to **all** eligible Q/As :)

Answer (score 5):

I quite liked this question from new user kviiri. Short, succinct and surprisingly answerable

- [What did Godric Gryffindor have a sword for, anyway?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/88072/what-did-godric-gryffindor-have-a-sword-for-anyway)

In terms of answers, I was especially proud of the one below. I spent a lot of time playing with the custom map and finally decided to make a video to demonstrate what I was talking about. The fact that it didn't get many upvotes or an acceptance didn't even bother me (that much). A good answer is its own reward :-)

- [In the Movie Gravity, where does Sandra Bullock's character end up?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81430/in-the-movie-gravity-where-does-sandra-bullocks-character-end-up/81435#81435)

@SS's demands seemed quite unreasonable at first glance, but with a bit of work, this question was actually pretty fun to answer:

- [How many people know that Harry owns an Invisibility Cloak?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85471/how-many-people-know-that-harry-owns-an-invisibility-cloak/85472#85472)

Answer (score 5):

I really enjoyed @Richard's answer to my question

- [Why does Han Solo's carbonite slab have a vital signs panel on the edge?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/91298/why-does-han-solos-carbonite-slab-have-a-vital-signs-panel-on-the-edge)

It is succinct and answers every part of the question, and the chosen illustration is perfect.  It also introduced me to a book that I was not aware of...I have lost hours to it now, for better or worse.

@JasonBaker's answer to

- [In The Avengers, how is it possible that the Hulk can overpower the god Loki?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/89934/40294)

is brilliant.

Last but not least, I very much enjoyed @JasonBaker's thorough answer to

- [How do we reach Ultima?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/91601/how-do-we-reach-ultima),

even though it wasn't the answer I wanted to hear!

Answer (score 4):

My favorite questions were:

- Praxis' [Nacelles: if two are better than one, then why are three not better than two?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/91879/nacelles-if-two-are-better-than-one-then-why-are-three-not-better-than-two)

and

- Richard's [Why is Max Mad?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90591/why-is-max-mad)

My favorite answers were:

- [Richard's response](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87536/why-does-the-batmobile-have-a-no-step-sign/87548#87548) to 'Why does the Batmobile have a “NO STEP” sign?' (and if comments count,  Boelabaal's comment for that question)
- Richard's response to [What is the benefit of a hover-car over a standard ground-car?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87336/what-is-the-benefit-of-a-hover-car-over-a-standard-ground-car)

Answer (score 1):

## My favourite answer

**Nika G.** posted an excellent answer to [Why would Arya join the Faceless Men?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/91309/21267)

- [**She wants revenge. She's hungry for the blood.**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/91371/21267)

  - Well researched
  - Excellent analysis of how exactly she progressed from The Saltpans (previously known as Whitewalls) to The House of Black and White
  - It tied-in her connection to Jaqen / The Faceless Men
  - Tied-in her want for revenge
  - All backed-up by relevant canon

## My favourite question

**The Honorable Ned Stark** asked about the [**Origin of the name Azor Ahai**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/91866/21267)

- It's always good to ask the seemingly unanswerable questions
- Made me question the importance of names made up by George R. R. Martin
- Sent me delving into the depths of my favourite canon
- I had a lot of fun trying to find a suitable answer
- Made me learn *so much*, including that George R. R. Martin is extremely deliberate with his name choices!
- I *maaay* have earned some extra rep from the bounty offered by @Arm0geddon